# Alerts across multiple timeframes in one Tradingview script

Tags: pine-script

I have been trading a certain set of parameters manually for a while but wanted to see if I could set up something to alert me when that set of criteria is matched. I have a custom outside bar script that runs along with a bunch of MA's and then I eyeball things every couple of hours.

With the way TV does alerts, if I want to set H2, H4, H8 and 1D alerts I have to set one alert for each of the 28 currency pairs across four different timeframes eg over 100 alerts to set manually.

However, I would like to be able to put script on one chart that looks across a range of timeframes and alerts me if my criteria is hit across any timeframe I set. So then I would only have to set one alert per currency pair.

I have tried a few things but can't get it working yet so I was thinking I should check if it's even possible to do this? I have a script on JForex that does this well but much prefer TV.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not possible. You have to set alerts for each time frame manually.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - that's disappointing. I get they want us all to pay for a higher monthly fee for alerts but it really is a very clunky system at the moment. Back to JForex I guess.